# Jquery doesn't execute callback function until f12 is pressed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've created an application on my pc and it works very good. I wanted to put my application online so I bought my webhotel from one.com, I uploaded the application and wanted to try it out. While I was trying it out I noticed that jQuery didn't execute the callback-function that was inherited from a `$.get` function. As soon as I pressed the f12-button it started to execute the callback-function.

```
$.get('php/read_Everything_log.php',{who:$('.adminName').html(),ri:$('.adminRight').html(),db:logDbTable,what: $('.logsFor_Everything_bottom_input').val(),dp:dpch,op:opch,scrollTop: scrollLogs},function (dataxr) {
    $('.logsFor_Everything_top_holder').html('').html(dataxr);
    logsCount=$('.logsCount').text();
    setTimeout(checkLogBaracks,90);
});
```

My question is: Why?
I got no errors and as I said it's works perfectly on my pc!

Comment: Perhaps a sample of the callback-function you're using...

Comment: There are alot of codes but if you want to I can paste it here?

Comment: Sorry what? That doesn't make any sense. You need to share the minimal code that replicates the problem.

Comment: It's strange to use html() to get the value of a parameter to send throught an http request. It's an input (.adminName), better use .val() value. But it must not be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Apparently one.coms' server doesn't approve sending an AJAX-Request from the `$.get` function so I had change it to `$.post`